# How to rotate a game object in runtime in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can I rotate something in unity in runtime?

I tried:

```
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(x,y,z));
```

,

```
transform.Rotate(x,y,z);
```

,

```
transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(x,y,z)
```

Nothing I tried worked.

Comment: What happened? What was expected to happen? What are x, y, and z? Can you include the entire script? Screenshot of inspector?

Answer (score 2):

To rotate a GameObject in Unity, the best way is using the **Rotate** function:

```
public float speed = 20f

public void Update()
{
    transform.Rotate(Vector3.right * speed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

With this code, your **GameObject** will rotate to the right, you can use **Vector3.up** or **Vector3.forward**.

If you only want to set a new rotation for your **GameObject**, change the **localEulerAngles** of the transform component:

```
transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(x, y, z);
```

Comment: I don't want to rotate the object slowly to the position, I want to set the rotation X Y Z to a certain X Y Z

Comment: Use localEulerAngles if you want to set a new rotation.

Answer (score 1):

`transform.Rotate (new Vector3 (0, 0, 45) * Time.deltaTime);`

Visit this site, it will help you https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/collectable-objects#

sorry if I am wrong

Comment: I need to rotate the object to a certain position

Comment: check this https://answers.unity.com/questions/140701/rotate-to-a-certain-position.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rotate to a certain position, I recommend using:

```
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(Vector3.forward * degrees);
```